# Experimenting with java generics

Tags: java, generics, casting

I was playing little bit with java generics, I came across this piece of code, which I am confused why it is happening so.

I am passing my second parameter `K` as `Integer` and inside generic method I was casting `float` to my `K` type, and in `main()` I am receiving it as `Integer`,

In my Code inspector I was seeing the `Float` number completely sitting in my list (not chopped after casting to `Integer`) which is of `Integer` type, but when I try to pick element to save it in `Integer` variable it gives `ClassCastException`.

Can someone explain what is going wrong with generics so it is not saving us from casting exception.

**Note** : I reach to this scenario when I removed my second parameter `K` from signature so there will be nothing defining type of `K` , in that case I think Java make it `Object` and then possibly we get cast exception but why in this case when I am passing `K` type as well.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class IntegerPrinter {

    Integer item;
    
    public void  print() {
        System.out.println(item);
    }
    
    public <T,K> List<K>  anyPrint(List<T> num,K lo) {
        List<K> mylist = new ArrayList<>();
        mylist.add( (K) new Float(2.99f));
        return mylist;
    }

    public  IntegerPrinter(Integer item) {
        this.item = item;
    }
}
```

- 

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class GenericsInAction {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        IntegerPrinter oldPrinter = new IntegerPrinter(188);
        oldPrinter.print();
        List<Integer> dates = oldPrinter.anyPrint(new ArrayList<Integer>(),7);
        Integer x = dates.get(0);
        
        
    }
}
```

Comment: "but why in this case when I am passing K type as well" Because generics don't matter at runtime. They get totally ignored. The situation is exactly the same as if you had removed `K`. Generics only add more *compile-time* checks.

Comment: @Sweeper the "strange" thing is that the JLS states "the compiler must ensure the checks, but only when necessary". This can result in some weird situations.

Comment: @Sweeper to be very honest I didnt get what you said , can you please elaborate so that I can understand it more better

Answer (score 2):

I condensed the code down to the essential parts and modified it slightly to highlight the behaviour that is important:

```
class Ideone {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> dates = new IntegerPrinter().anyPrint(7);
    System.out.println(dates.get(0)); // succeeds
    Integer x = dates.get(0);         // Line 8, throws
  }
}

class IntegerPrinter {
  public <K> List<K> anyPrint(K lo) {
    List<K> mylist = new ArrayList<>();
    mylist.add((K) Float.valueOf(2.99f));
    return mylist;
  }
}
```

When executed, this program will result in the following output:

```
2.99
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.Float cannot be cast to class java.lang.Integer (java.lang.Float and java.lang.Integer are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
    at Ideone.main(Main.java:8)
```

[<kbd>`Ideone.com` demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/X5ZW3Y)

Now, let us step through the code and try to understand what is going on.

This line:

```
mylist.add((K) new Float(2.99f));
```

basically tells the compiler "do not care for the type, we (as programmers) guarantee that it is a `K`, tread it as a `K`".

Then, if we dig deeper, we see that [`ArrayList` uses an `Object[]` as backing data structure](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk11/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/ArrayList.java#L136). So there is no problem here, the backing `Object[] elementData` can store everything.

Things get weird when we start retrieving elements. The JLS is somewhat vague about the type assertions in those cases (I **think** they are covered under [§5.1.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.5) and [§5.1.6.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.6.3), but I am not entirely sure). It basically says "the compiler has to assert the types, but only when necessary".

So if we retrieve an element from our `List<Integer>`, that clearly is not an `Integer`, but is passed along to a method that can deal with `Object`, no type-assertion is necessary. This is exactly the case here:

```
System.out.println(dates.get(0));
```

The closest signature matching in `System.out` is the [`println(Object)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/io/PrintStream.html#println(java.lang.Object)) method. This is the situation in JLS, [§5.1.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.5): a widening conversion, it will never throw.

On the other hand, if we now try to retrieve an `Integer` and try to store it in an `Integer`:

```
Integer x = dates.get(0);
```

Now, a type check is in place. And indeed, if we check the output of the program, we see that the `System.out.println(...)` took place, but the assignment to an `Integer`-variable was the statement that triggered the `ClassCastException`. This is the situation described in JLS, [§5.1.6.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.6.3): a narrowing conversion at run time (that comes from `ArrayList`'s [`elementData(int)` method](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk11/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/ArrayList.java#L457)).

---

#### Footnote

Generics are most certainly one of the most, if not **the** most, complex and confusing parts in the JLS. I made a best-effort attempt to cite the JLS on its relevant parts, this might be miss-cited. I also know that this question was asked before, but I am unable to find the duplicate.

Comment: I don't think "only when necessary" is "vague", at least in this particular case. Since you are assigning `dates.get(0)` to a variable of type `Integer`, why *wouldn't* it be necessary to cast the result to `Integer`? And yeah, I believe this is a duplicate too - I remember answering something very similar myself - but just couldn't find it! :)

Comment: @Sweeper I'd like to find the duplicate I wrote about, since I know that the compiler has some freedom as to where it can place the assertion. I know that I have seen stack traces with unexpected line numbers in them. That the check must be made is not "vague", the "where" is (somewhat) vague.

Comment: Really? I would really like to see such a case. Hope you find the dupe!

Comment: @Sweeper I think i was able to [reconstruct the example that threw past-me off (`Ideone.com`)](https://ideone.com/0s6XtD). What threw me off back then was the fact that the exception occurs on line `8`, not on line `14`. Today-me understands why...

Answer (score 0):

Since `ArrayList` is a generic type whose type erasure is `java.lang.Object`, that is what is stored in the list.  You can think of the type erasure as being the run-time type, the "real" type, as opposed to the compile-time type that the compiler knows about.  Any type can be stored in the `ArrayList` when the program runs.

It just so happens the the type erasure of K in `anyPrint` is also `java.lang.Object`, because you have no bounds on the type K.  The method is compiled once for all usages, and it must be able to accept any type for K.  So when the code for `anyPrint` is compiled, the cast to K in the line `mylist.add( (K) new Float(2.99f));` is ignored, since the type erasure of K is `java.lang.Object`.  Casting to `java.lang.Object` is useless and pointless.  It compiles as `mylist.add(new Float(2.99f));` and the code inserts an object of type `java.lang.Float` into a list of type `java.lang.Object`.

Also, a cast in Java on an object type simply ensures the object has the correct type, it does not change the values of the object, like a cast on a primitive type.  So there is no reason for you to believe the value 2.99f could change.

`GenericsInAction` is compiled separately.

The parametrized type of K is `java.lang.Integer` in the `main` method of `GenericsInAction`, since you pass in a `7` which is converted to `java.lang.Integer` via auto-boxing, to be compatible with the type erasure of `java.lang.Object` in `anyPrint`.  So, when that `main` method is compiled, the compiler inserts a run-time check, a checkcast, right after the call to `dates.get`, a check that ensures that the call to `dates.get(0);` dates returns an object of type `java.lang.Integer`, since the type of K must be `java.lang.Integer` inside `main`.

Since you inserted a `java.lang.Float` into the list, that run-time check fails and throws `ClassCastException`.